# Best practices with custom NSManagedObjects

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I receive lots of messages as a part of app logic which I want to store to persistent storage , I am using core data for the same , I have created a NSManagedObject subclass which represents message entity in my model. I want to know what is the best approach to create the object and save it, 
1. The object will be created and saved 
2. The object will be retrieved, updated and saved.

I want to make sure I use same managed context while saving the object , currently app is facing random freezes or crashes, which I suspect are due to improper use of context. Below is how the object is created and saved.

```
class MessageFactory: NSObject {


static func createMessage(state:Int,type:MessageType) -> Message {

    let appDelegate = AppDelegate.shared()

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext  // persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Message", in: context)

    let message = Message(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    message.setup(state:state,type:type)
    return message
}
}

class Message : NSManagedObject {
    var currentState: MessageState?

    @NSManaged var type : String
    @NSManaged var duration : String
    @NSManaged var mediaUrl : String

    func save() -> Bool {

      do {
        try self.managedObjectContext?.save()
        return true
      }
      catch {
        return false
      }
   }
}
```

Also I am passing this object to few functions as well , modify them there and save .

When I am passing this object to closure I am passing its ID and retrieving object using ID inside closure and them processing it.

I want to know if my above method is correct , if not what changes are needed.

Comment: Some notes: • The `save` method is supposed to be located in the *controller* not in the *model*. • The managed object context is supposed to be non-optional. • Rather than returning a `Bool` make `save()` *can throw* and pass-through the error `func save() throws { return try self.managedObjectContext?.save() }`

Comment: @vadian I have a question about save method , as you suggest it should be in controller , and if the object is fetched from core data and not created , after updating how do I save it ? Just get the managed object and call save ? Will that save the changes made to the properties ?

Comment: *"...currently app is facing random freezes or crashes..."* It would be useful if your question included some details of this, for example any error messages printed in the Xcode console.

Comment: @TomHarrington they are mostly SIGSTOPs , no errors in console